# ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture i386 xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, xcode5

I created iphone/ipad app that was working well by xcode 4 and iOS6 
and I installed xcode 5 and I'm trying to run my app, but it now gives me the following error

[image]

```
ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix this? hope anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I solved it. I was forgot to change the deployment target to 7.0 and it was 3.

Comment: Its not necessary to post a separate answer(Unless the solution is differ from all the post of your question) once your problem get solved. You should accept  user868754 answer.

Comment: Updating deployment target did the trick. You can find it in Project > Targets > General > Deployment Info > Deployment Target

Comment: Its bad by giving accept answer to your own answer. You degrade @jerryZhou.

Answer (score 74):

For me, I also need to set up the `Deployment Target` from `older version 3.0` to `7.0`.

Comment: What does it mean to set the deployment target to 7?

Comment: @tofutim that means change you application's lowest support to iOS7.0. So the build will not check the stuff that was overdue on the iOS 7.0+. And this setting you can change in the General->Deployment Info

Answer (score 22):

You need to change the Architecture is armv7 only.

[image]

if compiler is GCC, change to LLVM also,

[image]

And also need to change the deployment target 3.0 to 7.0.

Comment: I done both of these, done clean and run.. It still gives me the same error. :S

Comment: My architecture is (armv7, armv7s)

Comment: remove armv7s. i'm also facing this issue. i have added armv7 only, it is working for me.

Comment: when I added armv7 only it gives me many errors Apple LLVM 5.0 errors. :S

Comment: are you set Yes for "Build Active Architectue Only"?

Comment: it now gives me `ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/dt4it/Documents/iktab19/GTKeyboardHelper.framework/GTKeyboardHelper, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/dt4it/Documents/iktab19/GTKeyboardHelper.framework/GTKeyboardHelper (3 slices)
ld: symbol dyld_stub_binding_helper not found, normally in crt1.o/dylib1.o/bundle1.o for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: look at this screenshots: http://dt-works.com/emy/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-03%20at%202.39.03%20PM.png    http://dt-works.com/emy/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-03%20at%202.39.29%20PM.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38550/discussion-between-karthika-and-eman87)

Comment: First screen shot is wrong. Double click the architecture,  click - button  to remove existing one, and click + button to add armv7 alone..

Comment: could I add you on skype and share screens with you, please ??

Comment: http://dt-works.com/emy/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-03%20at%203.26.39%20PM.png  I done it as armv7 and still gives me the same error

Comment: http://dt-works.com/emy/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-03%20at%2010.26.59%20PM.png - still the same error :(

Comment: I solved it. I was forgot to change the deployment target to 7.0 and it was 3.

Comment: +1, Thanx this answer has helped me in my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057943/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-for-opencv-project/23061056?noredirect=1#comment35239632_23061056