# undefined reference for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using PDFTron iOS library in my application, after adding required files and libraries when i run the app it is showing some error named"undefined reference for architecture i386". I have gone through the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdfnet-sdk/jYNvzQQLcH0 and did the suggested modifications. Still i am getitng the error.

Project Specification-

1. Xcode5
2. Architecture-armv7,arvm7s
3. OS Version-iOS7

Can any one please help me.

Comment: Check the relevant library files are added properly.

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157977/ld-symbol-dyld-stub-binding-helper-not-found-normally-in-crt1-o-dylib1-o-bundl/19158212#19158212